# Need password to login once i edit sudoers file

Tags: sudo

I have installed Ubuntu Amazon ec2 instance and got the following error:

First I use ppk key and ubuntu as username and I was able to login to my system and I use `sudo su` command to get root access (without any password) there were no problem, then I made the following change in file `/etc/sudoers`

```
#add line 
Ubuntu ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Now when I connect using ssh it get connected, but when I use `sudo su` command it ask password but I have no idea what the password is how to solve this?

(I think it will give root privileges and I don't need to use sudo command each time when I run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, but now I can not access my root account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What happened

Case matters. If your account name is `ubuntu`, and you gave permission to `Ubuntu`, then you are stuck.

It looks like you locked your self out.

## A solution

The easiest solution is (probably) to delete the instance, and create a new one.

## A more complex solution (partial)

**If** you will loose data if you do this. Then there will be ways to mount the file-system on another OS instance, edit the config-file, and then re-try. (if this is the case, then update question to tell us.)

Comment: Assuming AWS exposes the system console, it may be possible to boot to single user mode.  Potential blockers on this route are if grub is locked down with a password and/or the system requires the root password for SUM.